# Twilio statusCallback: answer call or not

Tags: twilio

I use Twilio to make phone calls during which the user can reply by pressing key. My problem is that I want to manage 4 cases:

1) the user answer and press 1

2) the user answer and press another key than 1

3) the user answer and press no key

4) the user don't answer

For cases 1, 2 and 3, everything is OK: 
I have a "Gather" in my XML, with an "action" URL, a time-out and a actionOnEmptyResult="true"

For managing case 4, I use a statusCallback url, with 'statusCallbackEvent' => ['answered','completed']

What I notice in my Log is that I receive exactly the same data in case 3 (user answer but press nothing) and in case 4 (user don't answer the call).
Maybe this came from the fact after a few "rings" the call fall in voice-box, fooling Twilio which believe it's an "answer" event.

In my LOG I see (case 3 or 4) this 3 events:

- Call to my statusCallback with CallStatus = in-progress
- Call to my return hook with msg = Gather End and Digits = ""
- Call to my statusCallback with CallStatus = completed

So my question is: how can I know the difference between "answer the call and press nothing" and "don't answer the call" ?

Edit: if I refuse the call, result is the same. So I get the same "hook" and statusCallback call, with same data if the user pick-up and give no reply, if he doesn't pick up or if he refuses the call...

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You may want to handle the "doesn't answer the call" slightly differently. If the user doesn't answer, your action URL is still called but the [parameter `CallStatus`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml#callstatus-values) sent to the webhook will be `no-answer`. In this case you can [`<Hangup/>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/hangup) the call and mark it as not answered.

There is one other issue. If the call is answered by a voicemail then your call will attempt to continue as normal. You can put this down as a call that was answered but didn't enter anything, or you can try using [Twilio's answer machine detection](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/answering-machine-detection) to detect whether a human or machine answered the call. If it's a human you continue as usual, but if a machine answers you can also mark it as not answered and `<Hangup/>` the call.

Let me know if this helps at all.

Comment: Well...  when I log all the POST values I receive in my action code (Gather action in the XML) or in my status code (set with statusCallback) I notice there is no DialCallStatus parameter.... :/ I'll send you the LOG by email.

Comment: Oops, I meant `CallStatus` rather than `DialCallStatus` (which is only for calls made with `<Dial>`.